# Toilet auger used but water level dropped only a little — is clog cleared? Have not flushed, yet

Tags: plumbing

Auger extended six feet into toilet but water level dropped only a little. Toilet has not been flushed yet (am afraid of filling bowl again with “dirty” water).  Is clog likely cleared? Should auger be used again? Try flushing or using plunger?  Other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Toilets have build in something called the p-trap, in the toilet.

It is basically U shaped so water has to go down and then up then to the drain pipe.

It prevents the sewage smells coming back.

To do so the trap always hold some water left in it and that is the water you see. = Normal

Before you flush the 2 gallons from toilet, use a bucket with preferably hot water and flush with 1/2 gallon to see if it quickly drains away.

To visualize the draining away, put in a small pice of toilet paper and watch it disappear when flushing with bucket.

The draining suction has to be strong and for a moment it looks like all the water is gone, but then it fills up back to normal level.

Comment: Thanks. Think I was just accustomed to a quick drain, as has happened after using a plunger.

Comment: @Mitch than all is fine ?

Comment: After following the hot water tip, everything is flowing well!  Thanks again.

Comment: @Mitch feel free to acknowledge my answer as correct for others to find